# Как реализовать маршрутизацию на чистом node js (без express)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как реализовать нормально маршрутизацию на чистом node js (без express)? Код, который я привожу ниже, устраивал меня до тех пор, пока я не столкнулся с get-запросами с параметрами. Тогда я понял, что его надо переписывать, но не могу найти примеров. Может есть у кого примеры маршрутизации на чистой ноде или идеи как сделать?

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'login.html' : req.url)
    const ext = path.extname(filePath)
    let contentType = 'text/html'

    switch (ext) {
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css'
            break
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript'
            break
        default:
            contentType = 'text/html'
    }

    if (!ext) {
        filePath += '.html'
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'error.html'), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(500)
                    res.end('Error')
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text.html'
                    })

                    res.end(data)
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': contentType
            })

            dbConnect()

            if (req.url === '/login' && req.method === 'POST') {
                loginApp(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/registration' && req.method === 'POST') {
                regApp(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/new_post' && req.method === 'POST') {
                createNewPost(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/main' && req.method === 'POST') {
                deletePost(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/main') {
                renderPosts(res)
            } else {
                res.end(content)
            }
        }
    })

})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server has been started on ${PORT}...`)
})
```

Даже, например, на адрес `/main` не могу обработать get-запрос с параметрами.

Comment: Здесь есть - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ufxj0oTaUo&t=1713s

Comment: [node basic routing](https://canonium.com/articles/series-getting-started-node-part-2-basic-routing/)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html - делишь на части и используешь по отдельности. А ещё у тебя дыра в безопасности когда запросят адрес на `../../../../../`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно подбробнее про "делишь на части и используешь по отдельности" и что именно смотреть в документации по url?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathname

Answer (score 0):

1. Отправляйте с фронта POST-запрос, в body положите некий ключ.
2. На сервере принимаете POST-запрос, проверяете на предмет данного ключа, выполняете необходимые операции, и отправляете ответ на фронт.
3. На фронте получаете данные.
4. вот вам и "GET"-запрос.

Comment: если отправлять POST запрос - он не станет GET

Comment: @Grundy "GET" в кавычках. Что это значит, одному автору известно.